# How to redirect another activity after successfully login with facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am implementing face book api in my application,I have one login
button for  Facebook.

Whenever I press this button for Facebook login, it is working fine. Now I want to redirect another activity while I was successfully login with Facebook.

How to implement to do this, how can I implement call back method for that? Please help me.

Comment: @i want to redirect to my activity after successful login with Facebook.How to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the Facebook SDK, as can be seen in my example:

```
mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "friends_birthday", "friends_about_me", "read_friendlists" }, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle arg0) {

                //start activity here. 

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        });
```

To start an activity in general (put this in `onComplete()`):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, make sure that you add the Target Activity into your AndroidManifest.xml. You must do this in `<activity/>` tags. Without this, your application will crash.